# Show that $g$ is a constant function (Calculus 2)

Tags: calculus, integration

Show that $g$ is a constant function.

> $$g(x) = \int_x^{x+\pi}sin^{2/3}t\text{ dt} $$

I just started calculus 2 and this is on a graded worksheet. I have asked several of my peers but no one knows how to do it.

Comment: Hint:  usually when I'm asked about something being constant, I ponder what the derivative has to say about it.

Comment: $\sin x\geq 0$ for $[0,\pi]$ and $\sin x\leq 0$ for $[\pi,2\pi]$ How do you define $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ for $x<0$? if $x>0$ then $x+\pi\in [\pi,2\pi]$

Comment: Take the cube root and square it?  How is this a problem?

Comment: But cube roots can't.

Comment: LOL, sure.  I'm sure that's the intent of the question.

Comment: $x\rightarrow \sqrt[3]{x}$ is a "good" function defined on $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Obtain $g'(x)$ using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Also $t^{\frac23} = (-t)^\frac23$

Comment: $ (-t)^\frac23$ really? For t>0?

Comment: I got that $g'(x) = sin^{2/3}(x+\pi) - sin^{2/3}(x)$ but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: You can manipulate $\sin(x+\pi)$ into something friendlier...

Comment: @FDP:  take the cube root (defined for **all** inputs) and square it.  The square dumps the minus sign so $t^{2/3} = (-t)^{2/3}$.

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is defined for $x$ real.

Comment: Can someone help me out here?  I feel like I am going crazy.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Generally $x^\alpha:=\exp(\alpha\ln x)$ for $x>0$ and $\alpha$ real.

Comment: This seems like insanity to me.  It's Calc 2.  Cube roots are okay.

Comment: @Mist0_  please ask your instructor for the intended branch for cube roots and let us know what s/he says.

Comment: The problem is the meaning of $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Comment: Y'all are cracking me up.  Have a good day.

Comment: As far i know  the equation $x^3=k$ where $k$ is a real has only one solution in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{a}:=\text{the solution of equation  } x^3=a$

Answer (score 2):

For $x$ real let,

$\displaystyle F(x)=\int_0^{x}\sin^{2/3}t\text{ dt}$

$g(x)=F(x+\pi)-F(x)$

But for $x$ real,

$\displaystyle F^\prime(x)=\sin^{2/3}x$

Therefore,

$g^\prime(x)=\sin^{2/3}(x+\pi)-\sin^{2/3}x$

Since for $x$ real,

$\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin x$

Therefore, for $x$ real,

$g^{\prime}(x)=0$

Therefore $g$ is constant on $\mathbb{R}$.

NB:

For $x$ real,

$\displaystyle x^{\frac{2}{3}}:=\sqrt[3]{x^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is periodic with period $P$, shouldn't all integrals of type $$\int_x^{x+P} f(t) \;\mathrm{d}t$$ have the same value? Now if we can agree that $\sin^2$ has period $\pi$ ...